# Selecting multiple photos like Imessage and android messaging Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to display all images from the gallery like Imessage?

[Displaying images from gallery like imessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGy0y.png)

I need to be able to select the images from the gallery without going to the gallery

The app is using xamarin form 4.0

Comment: https://www.xamboy.com/2019/11/13/getting-device-media-and-show-it-using-xamarin-forms/

Comment: http://www.xamboy.com/2019/03/12/select-multiple-images-and-videos-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to select multiple image from Gallery, and I find two article about this, one is using CarouselView to display the selected image,

https://medium.com/swlh/select-multiple-images-from-the-gallery-in-xamarin-forms-df2e037be572

Another is using FlowListView to display the selected image.

https://xamgirl.com/select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thank you these will also help but is there a way to select photos without popping a new screen?

Comment: @DNguyen,It means that you want to select image without going to gallery? Now, I am not sure where do you select image, how do you choose picture?

Comment: Here's a image of the idea I'm looking for.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGy0y.png
The idea is to replace the keyboard with a mini gallery to select photos like Imessage on Iphones

Comment: @DNguyen, You mean that you want to choose image from mini gallery, the mini gallery display all image from Gallery?